# Fastest, best (fastest) way to modify data in in a pytorch loss function?

Tags: pytorch

I want to experiment with creating a modified Loss function for 4 channel image data.

What is the best way to split torch.Size([64, 4, 128, 128])

to

torch.Size([64, 3, 128, 128])
torch.Size([64, 1, 128, 128])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either slice the second axis and extract two tensors:

```
>>> a, b = x[:, :3], x[:, 3:]
>>> a.shape, b.shape
(64, 3, 128, 128), (64, 1, 128, 128)
```

Alternatively you can apply [`torch.split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html) on the first dimension:

```
>>> a, b = x.split(3, dim=1)
>>> a.shape, b.shape
(64, 3, 128, 128), (64, 1, 128, 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this myself by using the Split function.

Given an Image based Tensor like:  torch.Size([64, 4, 128, 128])

You can split on dim 1 and given a static length.

```
self.E1 = torch.split(self.E, 3, 1)
print(self.E1[0].shape);
print(self.E1[1].shape);
```

Gives:

```
torch.Size([64, 4, 128, 128])
torch.Size([64, 3, 128, 128])
torch.Size([64, 1, 128, 128])
```